# Mongoid.override_database in Sidekiq and simultaneous Rails requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, mongoid3

I'm just wandering when can I safely use `Mongoid.override_database`.
If I use it inside Sidekiq worker is DB going to be changed only for the worked which has called the `override_database` method?

How about using it in standard Rails controller? Is there any situation where it shouldn't be used (where it could cause problems)?

At first I've used `.with(database: 'xyz')` when I needed to change the DB, but then I've found out that it doesn't work on relational fields...

Comment: do you have any leads yet?